# VBA - Saving a workbook without ability to change content

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which create a copy of a workbook in VBA. I want this copy "Read Only", but the property `ReadOnly := True` doesn't work.

Here's the code:

The first macro:

```
Sub SaveXL()

Dim Nom2 As String
Dim Jour2 As String
Dim FPath2 As String
Jour2 = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd - h\hmm")
Nom2 = Jour2 & " Pricelist"
FPath2 = Sheets("PARAM").Range("B33").Value
On Error GoTo fin4
fichier = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FPath2 & Nom2, "Fichiers Excel (*.xls), *.xls")
If fichier <> "Faux" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fichier
    VBA.SetAttr fichier, vbReadOnly
    Test GetAName(fichier)
Else
    MsgBox "Le fichier n'a pas été enregistré"
End If
Exit Sub
fin4:         MsgBox "La création de l'excel a échoué"
End Sub
```

The second:

```
Sub Test(targetWorkbookName As String)
Dim F As Integer, C As Integer, derniereligne
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks(targetWorkbookName)
On Error GoTo 0
If (targetWorkbook Is Nothing) Then _
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename := targetWorkbookName, ReadOnly := True)
    
For F = 1 To Sheets.Count
    ActiveSheet.Select
    For C = 15 To 2 Step -1
        ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        derniereligne = ActiveCell.Row
        If ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Hidden = True Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Delete
        End If
    Next C
Next F
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("PARAM").Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 2")).Select
            Selection.Delete
 ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 9")).Select
            Selection.Delete

targetWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=targetWorkbookName,    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?"

Comment: one possible easier Approach ist to lock the worksheet and protect it with a Password. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx

Comment: @MacroMan : Error 400 :/
DoktorOSwaldo : Error 400 too, I placed it at the end of the macro Test(), it is ok ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the workbook *un-saveable* you can do the following instead:

In the `ThisWorkbook` module use:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

 Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Then got to the immediate window (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) and type:

`Application.EnableEvents = False` - hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   `ThisWorkbook.Save` - hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   `Application.EnableEvents = True` - hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now when a user tries to save the workbook it will simply cancel the save, meaning the data can't be *permanently* overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
```

Answer (score 0):

Read-only is a file system permission not one controlled by Excel

Read-only recommended is the Excel controlled version of it in with the user is prompted to open it as read-only (but they can choose no).

To save a copy of a workbook as read-only recommended you need to: -

1. Save a copy using `SaveCopyAs`
2. Open the copy
3. Save the copy using `SaveAs` with the property `ReadOnlyRecommended` set to true
4. Delete the previous copy made in the first instruction

Below is a small example of this:-
    Public Sub Make_Copy_ReadOnlyRec()
    Dim WkBk As Excel.Workbook

```
'Using SaveCopyAs
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Temp.xlsm"

'Open the copy
Set WkBk = Application.Workbooks.Open(Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Temp.xlsm")

    'Use save as to make it read only recommended
    WkBk.SaveAs Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Sample.xlsm", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, , , True

    'Close the now read only recommended copy
    WkBk.Close
Set WkBk = Nothing

'Delete the original copy
Kill Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Temp.xlsm"

End Sub
```